Apollo GraphQL client: programmatically extract pagination cursors
I am working on a Kotlin project where we use the Apollo GraphQL client library to execute complex GraphQL queries, each containing multiple sub-queries with individual pagination. For example:
query MyQuery($after1: String!, $after2: String!) {
  root {
    foo(first: 100, after: $after1) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        f1
        f2
      }
    }
    bar(first: 100, after: $after2) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        f1
        f2
      }
    }
  }
}

We are always interested in retrieving all available pages of the query result. Now I would like to write some generic code that can loop over an arbitrary query and run it multiple times, always properly updating the cursors after1 and after2.
Obviously, Apollo internally has all the required information to construct MyQuery.Data objects. However, MyQuery.Data cannot be programmatically traversed in a generic way. On the other hand, there is MyQuery, which can be programmatically traversed by accessing rootField() and its selections(). However, MyQuery does not contain any concrete data values that have been received.
How can MyQuery, MyQuery.Data, and possibly other objects be used to extract the values after1 and after2?
